# PHP error when uploading images using DevDemon Channel Images

Tags: expresso, php-errors, channel-images, devdemon

I'm getting the following error when trying to upload images to my site using DevDemon's Channel Images (v5.4.18):

> Server response was not as expected, probably a PHP error. OPEN ERROR

Clicking on the OPEN ERROR link presents me with a blank white screen.

I'm running EE 2.9.0 and also have the Expresso fieldtype installed (v3.3.3).
However, the Channel Images field is listed before the Expresso one, when editing my Entry. I noticed some other posts had found that to be a solution in the past.

Comment: I'd check the server error logs to hopefully provide you with some more information. Also you might want to reach out to the dev demon team. They have always been great for me when I've ran into issues that I couldn't figure out in the past.

Comment: Was there a fix for this? I'm getting this as well. I'm on Channel Images (v5.4.19)

Comment: I don't think I ever found a bulletproof solution. I seem to remember that uploading smaller JPEGs seemed to work sometimes. I think it might have been a PHP memory usage issue in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I had created a CI field, and the first Size/Action I created was Watermark (Image). I then added a Resize (Adaptive) action to this.

Uploading an image brought up this error.

I then removed the Watermark action, saved, then tried uploading again. Worked.
Re-added the watermark Image (using path images/layout/mywatermark.png), saved, then tried uploading. This time it worked.

So anyone that sees this error, (using Watermark) try removing/saving/re-adding the action.