# Channel Images on EE 3.5 error uploading files - no detailed message given

Tags: add-on, error, devdemon, channel-images

EE 3.5.15
Channel Images 6.0.4
PHP 7.2.13

I'm experiencing a weird error with Channel Images addon, i am not more able to upload files in channels' existing items or new ones.
The file looks like is completely uploaded (it reachs 100%) and then an error occurrs:

> Server response was not as expected, probably a PHP error. OPEN ERROR

"Open error" doesn't really help because the ajax call already thrown a js error, inspecting it show that the response text is a full web page (the front page).

It looks like something similar to what happened [in this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25705/php-error-when-uploading-images-using-devdemon-channel-images), but the given solutions (php memory and small files) are not helpful.

Trying to create new channel and a new channel_images field doesn't solve the issue.
The channel_images field definition shows that **it fails to test location**, loading the front page of the website inside the modal instead of the test results.

Many PHP 7 versions has been tested. The only thing that happened on the server are the PHP recompile occurred on december, and the hosting service stated that nothing changed.

Further details:

- the website is on shared hosting
- the native EE upload mechanism works
  properly
- double checked path and upload directory under Settings >
  URL and Path Settings and field detail
- caching driver is setted to
  "file"
- website is running PHP 7.2 and I am enough confindent all the
  needed php extensions are loaded
- the htaccess is the one from the EE manual

Do you have any hints where/what i can investigate?
Could the PHP recompilation be responsible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for my case is a conflict of the two plugins, Channel Images and Publisher.
With a specific setting of Publisher (add url prefix setted to yes) the Channel Images fails to upload any files. Some warnings involved the cache (fail to write) and i suspect something is wrong with my EE installation. I'm going with the rebuild of the website on a newest EE release.

The Publisher's support turned out to be immediate and helpful, while I have been waiting for a response from EEharbor for three weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a local copy of your applications code base, and are either running on a Linux/Unix OS or you use a modern IDE like PHP Storm, you can search that add-ons codebase for that error term, `OPEN ERROR`. It'll probably be in a language file for the add-on, which will give you the language key for that error message. In the language file, it'll probably look something like this:

```
"open_error_msg" => "OPEN ERROR"
```

The next step is to search the add-on code base for that key, `open_error_msg`. This should show you everywhere in the add-on code where that error is returned, and you can snoop out what is throwing the message.

If it's thrown from multiple places, you can add tracers to the add-on code. I usually do something like this:

```
file_put_contents ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/log_file.log", date("c") . " : " . __FILE__ . " : " . __FUNCTION__ . " : " . __LINE__ .  "\n\r", FILE_APPEND);
```

Drop that in where you think the issue is happening, and if log lines are showing up in that file (`{your_web_root}/log_file.log`) when you try to upload files, you've identified the code area returning the error. Work from there. I usually tail my log file when debugging unknown thrown errors on Linux using `tail -f ./log_file.log` live so I can get nuances as to when the issue occurs in the execution cycle.

Sorry, I really meant this more as a comment and not an answer since I don't use Channel-Images, but certainly couldn't shorten it to just a comment. But I have used this method to debug EE and EE add-ons many times.

Comment: thanks for your hints jrothafer. It looks like EE fails to load channel_images so the specified hook the should be triggered is never being invoked.The db row where hook info is stored looks regular. Furthermore, not even a single php error in the log